# Logging state of AdamW optimizer at certain stage in training

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm using an AdamW optimizer to train a model (Tensorflow 2.0).
I need to log its state at certain steps during training, so to be able to reload the optimizer's state and resume training from there later on.
Do I need to log anything else, apart from the initial config (the output of `optimizer.get_config()`) and its weights (the output of `optimizer.get_weights()`) in order to fully reconstruct the optimizer's state?

Comment: no - you don't. I don't even save `get_config()`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using keras [Model](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model), you can directly use `model.save` and then later restore it with [`tf.keras.models.load_model`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/models/load_model). This will ensure that the optimizer state is restored exactly as it was when saving.

Comment: not an option - unfortunately. It's a custom training loop where the optimizer is updated using GradientTape.